# Eclipse: Spring Explorer doesn't show beans configured using java files

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Recently I started wiring my beans in plain Java files annotated with `org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration`.

I prefer having compile time checks rather than XML string typos.
What's not so great (pretty bad actually) is that **Spring Explorer** in Eclipse (I am using Spring IDE plugin and Indigo release) doesn't show those configs at all in it's tree.

Is there something that I missed or isn't this feature supported yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read it somewhere on Spring web site that Java Config is not (yet) supported by STS views.  How soon, until they decide to do so, I don't know.

The Java Configuration IS supported by 3.0.x ( and even before ), but looks like a bastard child of Spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

STS Jira isue about this problem is in https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2309.

Partial solution is to add (but duplicate) `context:component-scan` tag to your xml spring configuration.

See for discussion on: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?118928-Spring-Explorer-with-Java-based-Web-Container-configuration.